# Change the color of vertices and lines using canvas.drawVertices

Tags: flutter, canvas

The regular `Paint` object doesn't seem to alter the appearance of any lines drawn using `drawVertices`. Here's what I've tried.

```dart
// Doesn't do anything
var brush = Paint()..color = Colors.blue..strokeWidth = 4..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

// The only shaders I've found are UI.Gradient and UI.ImageShader
brush = brush..shader = UI.Gradient.linear(
  Offset(0, 0),
  // absurd numbers
  Offset(10000, 10000),
  [Colors.blue, Colors.blue],
);

canvas.drawVertices(
  UI.Vertices.raw(
    VertexMode.triangleStrip,
    storage,
    // This will change the colors of the faces not the lines
    // colors: _encodeColorList(storageCount.map((_) => Colors.white).toList())
  ),
  BlendMode.dstIn,
  brush,
);


// Copied from dart:ui
Int32List _encodeColorList(List<Color> colors) {
  final int colorCount = colors.length;
  final Int32List result = Int32List(colorCount);
  for (int i = 0; i < colorCount; ++i) result[i] = colors[i].value;

  return result;
}
```

The line colors are always black:

[image]

EDIT:

It might be a framework bug. Here is the [Github issue for reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50492).

Comment: its because `colors` parameter is for faces not the lines, so you cannot use it for changing the particular line colors

Comment: Yes but the paint object doesn't change the line colors either (See the `brush` I pass into `drawVertices`). I've tried with and without a shader and with the `PaintingStyle` set to both `fill` and `stroke`. Those lines just don't want to change :\

Comment: i set `color` and it works but `strokeWidth` does not work - the lines are always "hair" style

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce getting color to work with `drawVertices` like you did. Here's a [gist of what I tried](https://gist.github.com/Nolence/b8c4cb59df2e48aa3e9c960d6f25663d). However, looking through some old flutter issues I found [this package](https://github.com/klaszlo8207/Flutter-OBJ-3D-Viewer) that is drawing edges with colors. A quick look around the code makes me think he's using `drawPaths` for the 3d object's lines and `drawVertices` for the faces and I'm thinking maybe `drawVertices` just doesn't support coloring or line thickness.

Comment: `var vertices = ui.Vertices(VertexMode.triangles, [Offset.zero, Offset(100, 0), Offset(100, 100)]);
canvas.translate(20, 50); canvas.drawVertices(vertices, BlendMode.srcOver, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
canvas.translate(20, 50); canvas.drawVertices(vertices, BlendMode.srcOver, Paint()..color = Colors.green);
canvas.translate(20, 50); canvas.drawVertices(vertices, BlendMode.srcOver, Paint()..color = Colors.blue);` - Flutter 1.14.7-pre.83 • channel master

Comment: Oh, I see.... Probably need to file a bug for this then. I was on stable but switched to master 1.15.3 and still saw no change. That was on [iOS](https://postimg.cc/18PN79MC). Opened an android simulator (still on master) and I can now [see colors](https://postimg.cc/Nyj2Yp3R). Thanks for your help @pskink! I'll link to the issue when I create it later today or tomorrow